# How to hide updated state from the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a form in using React and maintain state for storing form data. The form contains only text fields and radio buttons. There is a 'Proceed' button at the end whose onClick function goes like this :

```
handleClick(event){
    console.log(this.state);
    var userID = 1;
    firebase.database().ref('registrations/'+userID).set(this.state);
}
```

There is another function to handle input change like so :

```
handleInputChange(event){
    const target=event.target;
    const name=target.name;
    var value;
    if((target.type==="radio"&&target.checked)||target.type!=="radio") value=target.value;
    this.setState({
        [name]:value
    });

}
```

I want the console to log the updated state after filling the form and clicking the Proceed button. But when I fill the form and click the button, the state is briefly displayed on the console before disappearing (console goes back to how it was initially) and I see the form data in the URL instead. How do I stop the data being displayed in the URL and log the state data in the console?

I am relatively a beginner in React. So please bear with me if I don't know something very basic.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's render(), and please note that I also updated the click handler.

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>
        <div className="State">
            <div className="Head">
            State
            </div>
            <div className="StateField">
            <input 
                name="state"
                type="text"
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="Age">
            <div className="Head">
            Age
            </div>
            <div className="AgeField">
            <input
                name="age"
                type="number"
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="Ethnicity">
            <div className="Head">
            Ethnicity
            </div>
            <div className="EthnicityField">
            <input  name="ethnicity"    type="radio"    value="Hispanic or Latino"          onClick={this.handleInputChange} defaultChecked /> Hispanic or Latino
            <input  name="ethnicity"    type="radio"    value="Non-Hispanic or Non-Latino"  onClick={this.handleInputChange} /> Non-Hispanic or Non-Latino
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="Race">
            <div className="Head">
            Race
            </div>
            <div className="RaceField">
            <input name="race" type="radio" value="American Indian" onClick={this.handleInputChange} defaultChecked /> American Indian
            <input name="race" type="radio" value="Asian"           onClick={this.handleInputChange}/> Asian
            <input name="race" type="radio" value="Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander" onClick={this.handleInputChange}/> Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander
            <input name="race" type="radio" value="Black or African American" onClick={this.handleInputChange}/> Black or African American
            <input name="race" type="radio" value="White"           onClick={this.handleInputChange}/> White
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="Sex">
            <div className="Head">
            Sex
            </div>
            <div className="SexField">
            <input name="sex" type="radio" value="Male"     onClick={this.handleInputChange} defaultChecked /> Male
            <input name="sex" type="radio" value="Female"   onClick={this.handleInputChange}/> Female
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>  
        <div className="Height">
            <div className="Head">
            Height
            </div>
            <div className="HeightField">
            <input name="height" type="number" placeholder="In inches" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="Weight">
            <div className="Head">
            Weight
            </div>
            <div className="WeightField">
            <input name="weight" type="number" placeholder="In pounds" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="ProceedButton">
        <button name="Proceed" onClick={this.handleClick} >Proceed</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
```

And now I also realized that when I add the state to firebase realtime database, height, sex and weight fields are empty. Please point out if anything's wrong.

Comment: Please edit your post with the render method code as well. Especially the proceed button HTML. Thanks

Comment: @klugjo I have added render method. And now I am facing another issue with state. I've added it at the end.

Comment: My bad. Had forgot to add onChange for those fields.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code (apart from the missing handlers). Can you try to comment out the firebase call and see if it works ? Something is causing your page to reload. Is your code encapsulated inside a `<form>` tag somewhere else ? Check the rendered HTML in chrome debugger please

Comment: In your `handleInputChange function`.. have you tried to `console.log(value)` ? to check when you selected, and you get the value

Comment: @klugjo You were right, I had wrapped the entire class inside a form tag in my main app. And it all fell into place now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type of a button element is "submit". If you don't do anything to prevent it, clicking a button will submit a form that is an ancestor element of the button.

All the symptoms you describe are consistent with the button being inside a form  that has not been shown in the post.

Try addding `type="button" to the button definition:

```
<button name="Proceed" type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} >Proceed</button>
```